# How to find position for collision detection with rotated and non rotated objects?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

https://editor.p5js.org/bigboss01/sketches/OZLv0TPBn

This sketch illustrates the problem I'm having. I'd like to check the intersection of the arrowhead and the rectangle, but because the arrowhead is in a rotated space, it does not register the intersection appropriately.

I've seen this great tutorial on the separating axis theorem : https://dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/ , but I would appreciate some help connecting the dots as I don't fully understand how to implement this solution. I found [this library](https://github.com/bohnacker/p5js-screenPosition), but I would appreciate it if someone knew of a simpler way of doing this, as this seems like a fairly basic problem.

The problem I'm trying to solve [is in this sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/bigboss01/sketches/HNMEIalse) (a lot more code here, skip to this.update() in the rocket object for collision logic) that is from [this tutorial by Daniel Shiffman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGz7mv2vD6g&lc=UghQwhv23fiYjHgCoAEC), his version [is here](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/o5PwECj42), whose sketch does not seem to be having the same problem- my rockets do not get stuck in the bar, nor do they always register arrival to the target.

Comment: You might want to consider using a library such as [matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/) to solve this problem. Here's an example: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1241059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a [sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/Ult1/sketches/lX2xCCFQ8) for this.

No idea if it's the best way to do this, but it works for me.

Also Dan has a video on the `xSpeed = cos(a) * r` formula, it should be something like "polar to cartesian coordinates", or smth like that.

Also when you have an x (x + xSpeed !!!) you can use a "point-rect collision thingy", i just check `if(y > 300)`